# Why does logistic regression in Spark and R return different models for the same data?

Tags: machine-learning, r, logistic-regression, apache-spark

I've compared the logistic regression models on R (`glm`) and on Spark (`LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS`) on a dataset of 390 obs. of 14 variables.

The results are completely different in the intercept and the weights.
How to explain this?

Here is the results of Spark (LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS) :

```
model.intercept  : 
 1.119830027739959
model.weights :
 GEST    0.30798496002530473
 DILATE  0.28121771009716895
 EFFACE  0.01780105068588628
 CONSIS -0.22782058111362183
 CONTR  -0.8094592237248102
 MEMBRAN-1.788173534959893
 AGE    -0.05285751197750732
 STRAT  -1.6650305527536942
 GRAVID  0.38324952943210994
 PARIT  -0.9463956993328745
 DIAB   0.18151162744507293
 TRANSF -0.7413500749909346
 GEMEL  1.5953124037323745
```

Here is the result of R :

```
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)  3.0682091  3.3944407   0.904 0.366052    
GEST         0.0086545  0.1494487   0.058 0.953821    
DILATE       0.4898586  0.2049361   2.390 0.016835 *  
EFFACE       0.0131834  0.0059331   2.222 0.026283 *  
CONSIS       0.1598426  0.2332670   0.685 0.493196    
CONTR        0.0008504  0.5788959   0.001 0.998828    
MEMBRAN     -1.5497870  0.4215416  -3.676 0.000236 ***   
AGE         -0.0420145  0.0326184  -1.288 0.197725    
STRAT       -0.3781365  0.5860476  -0.645 0.518777    
GRAVID       0.1866430  0.1522925   1.226 0.220366    
PARIT       -0.6493312  0.2357530  -2.754 0.005882 **  
DIAB         0.0335458  0.2163165   0.155 0.876760    
TRANSF      -0.6239330  0.3396592  -1.837 0.066219 .  
GEMEL        2.2767331  1.0995245   2.071 0.038391 *  
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: I wouldn't call [Limited-memory BFGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS) a "simple logistic regression".  Except, I guess, in the sense that modern libraries make complex techniques very accessible :)

Comment: You are right. Do you know a way to implement Limited-memory BFGS with R ?

Comment: Also, suspect if it has something to do with the loss function http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/spark-liblinear/spark-liblinear.pdf
(Sec - IIIA) @SparkUser - is it possible to run LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS without the defaults and then compare the coefficients with the default R - glm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick glance at the [docs for LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS) indicates that it uses feature scaling and L2-Regularization by default. I suspect that R's `glm` is returning a maximum likelihood estimate of the model while Spark's `LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS` is returning a regularized model estimate. Note how the estimated model weights of the Spark model are all smaller in magnitude than those in the R model.

I'm not sure whether or not `glm` in R is implementing feature scaling, but this would also contribute to different model values.

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible to use feature scaling in R .. I can not find it..
Do you know how to perform logistic regression with LBFGS using R to compare the 2 models?

Comment: Here, check the documentation of function `glmnet` from `glmnet` package and look and parameter `standardize` [http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf) - there also is possibleto use regularization